# Ruby: Difference between Random#rand and Kernel#rand

Tags: ruby, random

Is there is really difference between Random#rand and Kernel#rand?

From what i can see they use different 'C' functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They behave the same when called with a `Range`, but differently in several other cases.

1. When called with a negative integer *-n* (like -3), `Random#rand`
   raises `ArgumentError`, while `Kernel#rand` just behave as if you
   called it with *n* (by `(-n).to_int.abs`).
2. When called with *0*, `Random#rand` raises `ArgumentError`, while
   `Kernel#rand` just behave as if you called it without any argument.
3. When called with `Float` *n*, `Random#rand` returns a float between 0
   and *n* (as expected). `Kernel#rand` do an `n.to_int.abs` conversion,
   so for example `rand(-1.9)` is equivalent to `rand(1)`, which always
   returns 0; `rand(0.1)` is equivalent to `rand(0)` and thus equivalent
   to `rand`.

It seems that `Random#rand` (and also `Random::rand` of course) is more robust than `Kernel#rand` for strange parameter. More information in documentation for [`Kernel#rand`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) and [`Random#rand`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Random.html#method-i-rand).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a slightly different API, but both seem to leave the actual generating to the `genrand_real` function.

Comment: My problem was that Random#rand gave us segfault without any reason. After switching to Kernel#rand issue solved.